# How to pass method get/post as a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, post, get

There are two almost the same functions. First function executes get().

```
function sendGet(url, $http) {
    $http
        .get(url)
        .then(function() {
            alert('Ok');
        }, function() {
            alert('Not Ok');
        });
}
```

Second post().

```
function sendPost(url, $http) {
    $http
        .post(url)
        .then(function() {
            alert('Ok');
        }, function() {
            alert('Not Ok');
        });
}
```

Is it possible to create more generic function which pass method get/post as a function parameter?

```
function sendGeneric(url, $http, methodCall) {
    $http
        .methodCall(url)
        .then(function() {
            alert('Ok');
        }, function() {
            alert('Not Ok');
        });
}
```

If yes how to execute such function?

Comment: `$http['post'](url).then(...)` would allow passing the method as string, e.g. `sendGeneric(url, 'post')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could just pass the desired function to the generic one:

```js
function sendGeneric(url, method) {
  method(url)
    .then(function() {
        alert('Ok');
    }, function() {
        alert('Not Ok');
    });
}
```

Call it like this:

```js
sendGeneric(url, $http.post);
sendGeneric(url, $http.get);
```

Or, for some more secure code:

```js
function sendGeneric(url, $http, method) {
  $http[method](url)
    .then(function() {
        alert('Ok');
    }, function() {
        alert('Not Ok');
    });
}
```

Call it like this:

```js
sendGeneric(url, $http, 'post');
sendGeneric(url, $http, 'get');
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable and set the method reference based on the string `methodCall` then finally execute!

```
function sendGeneric(url, $http, methodCall) {
    const callToMake = methodCall === 'get' ? $http.get : $http.post
    callToMake(url).then(function() {
            alert('Ok');
        }, function() {
            alert('Not Ok');
        });
}
```